# jQuery Mobile via "Download Builder Tool" -- Can't Make it Work

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to use just the slide transitions / AJAX navigation component of jQuery Mobile. On jQuery Mobile's website they have a "Custom Builder Tool" which lets you select just the "AJAX Navigation System" (and it auto-selects associated stuff like transitions).

http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

This yields some custom JavaScript and CSS files. For the life of me, I can't get this to work on a webpage. If I include these custom files, then add data-transition="slide" to an anchor element, nothing happens. If I include the full jQuery Mobile library it works perfectly (but screws up the styling of my mobile site). How can I make this work? Maybe one needs to initialize the custom jQuery Mobile manually? I can't find anything in the docs about this. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I got this to work:

I included the latest jQuery Mobile js but used the stripped down css from my custom JQM build (using the Custom Builder tool).

data-role="page" was added to page content containers. Some scripts called in  needed to be moved to now load from within the content containers. Now transitions work as expected.

I hope this helps somebody.